# In NextJS (App Router), How to get "destination" value of next.config.js rewrites() function in a client component

Tags: next.js, app-router

In my next.js project (App Router), I'm using rewrites() function in next.config.js file to rewrite url that enter by user to go to a specific route in my project.

The problem is after that I can't use usePathname() in Client Component to check which route do user in.

[image]

[image]

So how to get "destination" value (route in project after rewrite) in a client component

Example:

- User enter: [any-alias].domain.com
- Route in project after rewrite: domain.com/[any-alias]